# Windows 7 hangs before login screen

Tags: windows-7, windows

After a shutdown, my (Samsung)Windows 7 Home Premium laptop would not reboot completely, only getting to the blue screen with Windows 7 Home Premium at the bottom. The login icons would not appear so I could not get into windows (ie no msconfig, control panel, nada, really nada!).

I have lots of cr@p on it (apache, mysql, php, drupal, git, bash, putty, blah blah), so much that I really really didn't want to rebuild it. Everything's backed up but it was the reinstalling everything I squirmed at.

I tried EVERYTHING 'normal' to recover:
- boot in safe mode (it wouldn't, it hung before getting there)
- go back to previous restore points (it wouldn't and eventually there weren't any - I probably deleted them in my various attempots)
- use auto repair (didn't work, it didn't see anything wrong!)
- tried to use a backup copy of the registry (no change)
- Hiren, etc etc.

Googling told me this is quite common and I couldn't find a reliable solution, certainly nothing that worked for me. So I was left with a laptop that seemed to get almost to starting, but didn't quite make it. It was utterly useless.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what the computer looks like when it's stuck?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: We do allow self-answered questions, but the answer must be posted as an answer, and not part of the question. The question should be in a form answerable by anyone else (i.e. don't introduce new information about the problem in the answer, do so in the question instead). You should also make the answer more substantial than just the link - links do break over time. As it is, your question does not satisfy those requirements, and will likely be closed. If you can make those changes (separate the answer from the question), you can request a re-open on [meta].

Comment: Thanks Bob. I didn't know what the proper "form" was. I've amended it hopefully as it's meant to be.

Comment: @Caleb Sorry, too late it works now. I've tried to make it clearer in the question but imagine the PC screen just before the login icons appear, that would be it.

Comment: Had a look at the help centre and I think this fits in perfectly. It's about getting the windows operating system working on a laptop from a failed state. What could be more on topic than that?

Comment: I have a similar problem. The only way I would be able to take a screen shot would be to take a photo of the screen with a camera; Windows certainly doesn't have a mechanism to do it before it finishes booting up. But it's easy to describe: all black except for the mouse cursor (standard arrow pointing top left), which starts in the center but can be moved.

Comment: That was not my symptom. Mine had the normal blue screen but it never showed the user log in option. I presume you've tried all the standard options like booting in safe mode etc and reverting to a previous restore point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was left with a PC that was all but useless. Fearing that I would have to rebuild the laptop, I tried something a bit more radical.

(Remember that if you hit F8 when rebooting you get several options including a repair option. That eventually fires up a very very basic windows environment that includes a command prompt option. I used that to copy files.)

I have another laptop (with Windows 7 Enterprise) so I copied all the files from windows\system32 (NOT the sub-folders) to my dead laptop and... it worked. I don't know if I was lucky but I didn't complain! ***** THIS IS THE KEY STEP ******

The laptop then rebooted properly and I was able to login normally! From here I could use it normally.

I then used the tip from here: http://windowssecrets.com/top-story/win7s-no-reformat-nondestructive-reinstall/ to reinstall windows "properly". It took several hours but I now seem to have my laptop back with everything still there! Happy days!

(I'll be taking even more care now with backups!)

Comment: As others noted, links go dead. For me, this link describes the problem, and says one must answers a question to unlock the solution. I answered, and it said that I needed to become a member of the site, but offered no way to do thst. So without explaining the solution here, the answer would be useless.

Comment: Apologies. Looking at the link it looks like windowssecrets has changed since I used it and now that content is premium. I hope if you google around you'll find an alternative link that will help you. I'm afraid it was so long ago that I can't remember what that link contained. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution didn't work for me. Even a full Windows 7 reinstall and about two days of running Windows Update only got me back to limping functionality. I was only able to get the machine working again by updating to Windows 10.